# sympy lambdify: how to make more functions (NCDF, NPDF, etc) available

Tags: python, sympy, lambdify

How do I make sympy’s [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) accept more function names, like a Normal function, for example? To make something like this work:

```
lambdify(('x',), 'NPDF(x, 0, 1)')
```

I don’t mind using the `Normal` function from the sympy [`statistics`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/statistics.html) module, as long as it doesn’t create a new `Normal()` distribution object *every* time the lambda gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a numerical implementation of the function you want to use, pass it in the second argument, like

```
lambdify(x, NPDF(x, 0, 1), modules=['numpy', {'NPDF': NPDF_implementation}])
```

Comment: Do I need the `'numpy'` in front? And is there any way to use the built in normal distribution from sympy?

Comment: The 'numpy' in front is if you also want to use numpy (otherwise, only that one function will be defined for the lambdified function).